# How to parse 2 URLs in one activity using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-activity, retrofit2

How would I parse 2 or more URLs in one activity. Have 2 base URLs

```
private static final String BASE_URL_1 = "https://www.somesite.com";
private static final String BASE_URL_2 = "https://www.somesite.com";
```

They are processed in 2 separate methods. Each method instantiate `retrofit` library

1)

```
private void init(){
    //initialising retrofit
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_1)
            //converter XML
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    FeedTechCrunchAPI feedTechCrunch = retrofit.create(FeedTechCrunchAPI.class);

    Call<RssFeed> call = feedTechCrunch.getTechCrunch();

    //starting callbacks
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RssFeed>() 
}
```

2)

```
private void initActive(){
    //initialising retrofit
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_2)
            //converter XML
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    FeedVergeAPI feedVerge = retrofit.create(FeedVergeAPI.class);

    Call<FeedFeed> call = feedVerge.getFeedVerge();

    //starting callbacks
    call.enqueue(new Callback<FeedFeed>()
}
```

and I call these 2 methods in `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "starting");
    initActive();
    init();
}
```

But only `init()` is called. However, if I get rid of `init()` second one is called. Any ideas?
These are callbacks 
1

```
 public void onResponse(Call<RssFeed> call, Response<RssFeed> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: feed: " + response.body().toString());

            List<Item> mItems = response.body().getmChannel().getItems();

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Server Response: " + response.toString());
```

2

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RssFeed> call, Response<RssFeed> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: feed: " + response.body().toString());

            List<Item> mItems = response.body().getmChannel().getItems();

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Server Response: " + response.toString());
```

Comment: Could you put a log in `init()`, `initActive()` and inside each of the callbacks, and post the logcat logs?

Comment: There are no errors or crashes both functions are called. Logcat shows that
 two methods are called and displays the entries it's just these two feed are not showing up in the listview

Comment: Where do you implement the callback result ??

Comment: So both the network calls succeeds with valid response. If that's the case, I don't the problem is with the code that you have posted. It must in the way you populate the listview from the items obtained in the callback.

Comment: probably it is refreshing the list and showing you from your first or second call which is finished last. please create a List in your activity and add items on it from retrofit callbacks.